# Resistance of obstacles in one-dimensional quantum scattering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, scattering, s-matrix-theory

The transfer matrix in one-dimensional quantum mechanics, fulfills the property
\begin{align}
M_{12}=M_2M_1\,.
\end{align}
If we consider two obstacles, from the above matrix multiplication, it is possible to obtain
\begin{align}
 T_{12}=\frac{T_1T_2}{\left|1-\sqrt{R_1R_2}e^{i\theta}\right|^2}\,,
\end{align}
where $T_{i}=\left|t_i\right|^2$ and $R_i=\left|r_i\right|^2$ are the $i$th transmission and reflection amplitudes, respectively, and $\theta$ is the total phase accumulated during one complete internal reflection. According to [Müller and Delande](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.0915), if we define the expectation value of any function of $\theta$ as
\begin{align}
 \left\langle f(\theta)\right\rangle=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{2\pi} f(\theta)\,.
\end{align}
Then the expectation value of $T_{12}$ reads (see Eq. (15) of that review)
\begin{align}
 \label{eq: Expectation value}
 \left\langle T_{12}\right\rangle=\frac{T_1T_2}{1-R_1R_2}\,.
\end{align}
Moreover, if we define the resistance of obstacles $\left(1-T\right)/T$, the latter quantity fulfills the addition of every resistance $1$ and $2$,
\begin{align}
 \frac{1-T_{12}}{T_{12}}=\frac{1-T_1}{T_1}+\frac{1-T_2}{T_2}\,,
\end{align}
which corresponds to Eq. (16). I tried a lot to prove both, but it has been impossible for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using that $R_i+T_i=1$ from conservation of probability, I obtain:
$$
\frac{1-T_{12}}{T_{12}} = \frac{1-R_1R_2-T_1T_2}{T_1T_2} \\
= \frac{T_1(1-T_2)+T_2(1-T_1)}{T_1T_2} \\
= \frac{1-T_1}{T_1}+\frac{1-T_2}{1-T_2}
$$

For calculating the expected value, the quickest route is by the residue theorem, noting $r = \sqrt{R_1R_2} \in(0,1)$:
$$
\left\langle \frac{1}{|1-re^{i\theta}|^2}\right\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2\pi}\frac{1}{(1-re^{i\theta})(1-re^{-i\theta})} \\
= \oint\frac{dz}{2\pi i}\frac{1}{(1-rz)(z-r)}
$$
The integral is over the unit circle (anticlockwise), which encloses only the pole at $z=r$, the other being at $z=1/r$, so by the residue theorem:
$$
\left\langle \frac{1}{|1-re^{i\theta}|^2}\right\rangle = \frac{1}{1-r^2}
$$
so
$$
\langle T_{12}\rangle = \frac{T_1T_2}{1-R_1R_2}
$$
Note that you also obtain the compound reflection/transmission coefficient by a geometric series just like for the Fairy-Pérot interferometer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!